# Show database updation as notification like gmail Dashboard

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I create trigger table to track Insert/Delete or Update of specific table. Now I want to show that each trigger record as notification in Dashboard
(Like when we get email to gmail inbox)

If that trigger Table get 4 rows for 4 updates

I want show in the view Exactly Similar Like this

```
|====================|
|Dashboard           |
|  Notification(4)   |
|====================|
```

How can I achieve this problem